# SQL Hash table for words

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, sql, c

I'm trying to solve the "find all possible words for a set of letters" problems. There are some good answers out there, but I still can't figure it out.

In my first test, I put the whole dictionary in an array and then looped through each letter. This is super fast, but it takes forever to load the dictionary in the array, and requires huge amount of memory.

So I need to store the dictionary (750,000) letter is a sql database.

I guess there are two solutions to find all the possible words:

1. Make an advance query that returns all the possible words
2. Make a simple query that return a fraction of the database with words that might be possible, and then quickly loop through that array and valide the words.

**The problem?:** 
It must be super fast. An iPhone 4 need to be able to get all possible words in under 5-6 seconds so it doesn't hinder the game.

Here's a similar questions: 
[IOS: Sqlite. Find record fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344300/ios-sqlite-find-record-fast)

Sulthans answer seems like a good idea. Create a hash table, and then:

> Bitmask for ASCII letters (ignoring any non-ASCII alphabets). Bit at
>   position 0 means the word contains "a", at position 1 contains "b"
>   etc. If we create the same bitmask for our letters, we can select
>   words such as (wordMask & ~lettersMask) == 0

How do you make the bitmask, hash table, and how do you construct the sql query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

sql is probably not the best option. The traditional data structure for storing a collection of words is called a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). I'm sure there implementations out there you can find. Someone else will have an answer to that.

The algorithm I envision is to permute the letters you are given, and check each permutation to see if it is in the Trie.